# Change S7 IP-Address with snap7

Tags: snap7

Since my S7 1200 is not able to have the IP-Address assigned via dhcp (please correct me if I overlooked something) - Is it possible to change the IP-Address of my S7 through snap7?

For example with a snippet like this one (but it does not matter to me if it is a :

```
var snap7 = require('node-snap7');

var s7client = new snap7.S7Client();
s7client.ConnectTo('192.168.1.12', 0, 1, function(err) {
   s7client... // change ip address here
});
```

It doesn't matter if NodeJS or Python, a general hint would be helpful - maybe it's not possible at all?

Also: I know I can set the IP via TIA, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: No, no way to do it with Snap7.